# Using Datagrip with SqlServer: linked servers and autocomplete

Tags: sql-server, autocomplete, linked-server, datagrip

I connect [DataGrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/) (db IDE from JetBrains) to SqlServer instance which has links to another SqlServers (server objects -> linked servers), but DataGrip not see linked servers and their tables.
Is it possible to enable autocomplete in DataGrip to work with a linked server in SqlServer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible in the DataGrip 2021.1
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-3934